# Why include iostream despite including fstream though fstream is derived from iostream?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, fstream, turbo-c++

Till a while ago, I was using a C++ compiler with old standards(TurboC++), where, on including *fstream.h*, including *iostream.h* became needless(in order to use cout/cin, for example).

Now, when I switched to newer standard compiler, I find that I need to include *iostream* even after including *fstream*, despite the fact that *fstream* is derived from *iostream*.So, I want to know why it is needed to include *iostream* with *fstream* and increase compile time.

Comment: `fstream` is not derived from `iostream`.

Comment: If you are going to use only file streams and not stuff from `iostream` (`cin`/`cout`/...), then you do not need to include `iostream`

Comment: Check this nice [inheritance diagram](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot you do need to include `<istream>` or  `<ostream>` in order to use `ifstream` and `ofstream` respectively (and both for `fstream`)

Comment: @M.M Do you mean fstream-iostream relation isn't the same as fstream.h-iostream.h?

Comment: @M.M No, you do not. You will need a definition of `basic_istream`/`basic_ostream` because of the way file streams are described in standard, but it does not means that user have to include `istream`/`ostream`: it should be handled by implementation, which actually does not have to include those headers _exactly_.

Comment: @user4581301 please read qsn. carefully before commenting! :)

Comment: Yup. Brainless comment. Sorry.

Comment: @AyushJain `iostream.h` is not covered by any standard